# Rejection sampling in R

Tags: r, function, statistics

I'm doing rejection sampling for the density function  0.5sin(|x|) for -0.5<x<0.5.
These are the functions I created,

```
f <- function(x){ 
  ifelse((x<0.5 & x>-0.5), 0.5*sin(abs(x)), 0) 
} 

rf.reject <- function(n) {
M <- 0.24
results <- numeric()
while (length(results) < n) {
X <- runif(2*(n - length(results)), min = -0.5, max = 0.5)
Y <- M*runif(length(X))*1
keep <- Y < f(X)
results <- c(results, X[keep])
}
results[1:n]
}
```

But when I go to plot the histogram, the actual densities under the pdf f(x) differ from the densities under the histogram.

```
hist(rf.reject(10000), prob=TRUE, breaks = "Scott" )
curve(f(x), add=TRUE, col="red")
```

Side note: Candidate function g used for sampling is Unif[-1/2,1/2]

Comment: Your function `f()` isn't a normalized density.  It integrates to around 1/8.  The histogram is scaled to integrate to 1.